# Python Classes Problem. name not defined error

Tags: python, python-3.x

my main code is this:

```
import CarDefinition # <- change ONLY this line to point to your class definition file

def main():
    # Create an instance of Car
    my_car = CarDefinition.Car("2008", "Honda Accord")

    print("my_car after instantiating:\n", my_car)

    my_car.setSpeed(2)
    print("my_car after my_car.setSpeed(2):\n", my_car)
    # Accelerate 5 times
    print ("car is accelerating: ")
    for i in range(5):
        my_car.accelerate()
        print ("Current speed: ", my_car.getSpeed())

    print()
    # Brake 7 times
    print ("car is braking: ")
    for i in range(7):
        my_car.brake()
        print ("Current speed: ", my_car.getSpeed())

    print("my_car values at program end:\n", my_car)


main()
```

while my import CarDefinition is this:

```
class Car:
    __year_model = ""
    __make = ""
    __speed = 0

    def __init__(self, year_model, make):
        self.__year_model = year_model
        self.__make = make
        self.__speed = 0

    ############# year_model################
    def setYear_model(self, year_model):
        self.__year_model = year_model

    def getYear_model(self):
        return self.__year_model

    ############# Make################
    def setMake(self, make):
        self.__make = make

    def getMake(self):
        return self.make

    ############# speed################
    def setSpeed(self, inp_speed):
        if inp_speed < 0:
            print("Speed cannot be negative")
        else:
            self.__speed = inp_speed

    def getSpeed(self):
        return self.__speed

    ############# str ############
    def __str__(self):
        return "Make : " + self.__make + ", Model Year :" + \
            self.__year_model + ", speed =" + str(self.__speed)
```

Edit: folder structure is show here: [Folder Structure picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fSGKG.png)

my result comes out saying that NameError: name enter code here'CarDefinition' is not defined.

Yes this is a homework problem but I didnt come here to ask for my homework to be done for me. I've been looking through this for 2 days and I cannot find out how to get past line 5.
This portion I have posted is the default code I am to start with. I am only to code the Brake and Accelerate functions which I have no problem doing.
can someone please help point out what I am missing???
BTW, i'm using python 3.7

Comment: do you have your CarDefinition.py and the main code py under the same directory?

Comment: yes both are in the same directory

Comment: Please show us your folder structure, as well as how you're calling your script.

Comment: The import command should call up the CarDefinition File which contains my class. Folder structure pic is posted

Comment: Just remove CarDefinition from CarDefinition.Car("2008", "Honda Accord")   use Car("2008", "Honda Accord")  since importing the file already adds the definition of class car

Comment: You also need to define method accelerate and break in class car

Comment: Side-note: Any class that is teaching you to write `getSpeed` and `setSpeed` methods instead of just using raw attributes or (if programmatic behavior needed) an `@property` is taught by someone who converted their Java exercises to Python exercises in the laziest possible way. Especially obvious given the names; [Python's style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions) doesn't recommend `mixedCase` naming for anything (classes are `CapWords`, but `mixedCase` is only for 20 year old legacy code that predates PEP8 entirely); Java uses it all over the place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you do not have the files in the same directory.

I copied the code from both files and created this structure inside a folder:

```
drwxr-xr-x   4 foobar  staff  128 Dec 10 20:02 .
drwx------+ 13 foobar  staff  416 Dec 10 19:57 ..
-rw-r--r--@  1 foobar  staff  969 Dec 10 19:57 CarDefinition.py
-rw-r--r--@  1 foobar  staff  709 Dec 10 19:59 main.py
```

And afterwards executed the main.py file like so:

```
python main.py
```

And this was the output:

```
('my_car after instantiating:\n', <CarDefinition.Car instance at 0x108512950>)
('my_car after my_car.setSpeed(2):\n', <CarDefinition.Car instance at 0x108512950>)
car is accelerating:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 27, in <module>
    main()
  File "main.py", line 14, in main
    my_car.accelerate()
AttributeError: Car instance has no attribute 'accelerate'
```

I therefore suggest you review the location of the files, confirm that they are inside the same folder and try again. If you do so, you should not need to change any code. Have fun!

Comment: I moved my files to a different directory and I happened to get the result i wanted. THank you for this! no idea how this did not work before I made this post.

Comment: No problem @JasonMartin glad that I could help. Please upvote if you think I answered your question.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your main function when you are trying to create an instance of car.
you have just to write `my_car = Car("2008", "Honda Accord")` not `my_car = CarDefinition.Car("2008", "Honda Accord")`

I have run the code with the main given below and it runs fine.

```
def main():
# Create an instance of Car
my_car = Car("2008", "Honda Accord")

print("my_car after instantiating:\n", my_car)

my_car.setSpeed(2)
print("my_car after my_car.setSpeed(2):\n", my_car)
# Accelerate 5 times
print ("car is accelerating: ")
for i in range(5):
    #my_car.accelerate()
    print ("Current speed: ", my_car.getSpeed())

print()
# Brake 7 times
print ("car is braking: ")
for i in range(7):
    #my_car.brake()
    print ("Current speed: ", my_car.getSpeed())

print("my_car values at program end:\n", my_car)
main()
```

I have commented out the accelerate and brake functions calls because you have not yet implemented them.

Comment: That is exactly what I tried doing so that I can complete this code in steps. I commented out everything else and still had the error.

Answer (score 0):

My two files were saved in the same directory. But for some reason when I copied them to a new folder everything was working as it should. I dont know how else to answer this but it kinda reminds me of tech support asking the first question "is it plugged in?"
thank you for this help. leaving this with a bit of facepalm

Comment: Your error is a typo which is off-topic in SO, I recommend you uncheck the accepted answer and delete your question.